# Why fedoraproject.org does not provide an official download link for Everything repository?

Tags: linux, download, fedora, fedora-13, bittorrent

or even a torrent!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sheer size of the various versions along with the number of platforms and versions takes up a vast amount of space (12 to 20 GB per version-platform, 3 or 4 platforms per version, 7 versions) makes providing both individual packages and ISOs for the various media (CD, DVD, etc.) ridiculously expensive.

The Fedora Unity Project used to provide images containing Everything, but I don't know if they still do.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What is the cost for 1 Terra Byte today?!
For the bandwidth issue, this is why torrents are there.

Comment: Enterprise NAS storage is expensive; it's not just a matter of popping down to the local TigerDirect or Fry's and sticking another My Book on a shelf. And then the mirrors. Won't someone please think of the mirrors?!